# How to print rows with specific string onwards based on the last occurrence of a string in the file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, nsregularexpression

I have a text file `com.txt` and the content of that text file is shown below. There are many occurrences of a string `bring it on` in it and the program should be able to find the last occurrence of this string `bring it on` and print only those lines after the last occurrence onward that have a string `[err]`.

`a` = `'bring it on'`

`com.txt`

```
Error logs are useful in many respects.
bring it on
A network or system administrator can resolve errors more quickly and easily with the information available
from the error logs
bring it on
[err] - not found
Error logs also could provide insights on ha
bring it on
cooll in this way
[err] - there is no way
hopefully
err - back
success
```

Now the program should be able to find the last occurrence of a string `a` and find and print only those lines which have a string  `err`  after the last occurrence of a string `a` so the output would be only those lines that have a string `err` after the last occurrence of a string `a`

```
[err] - there is no way
err - back
```

I tried below code

```
with open('com.txt', 'r') as file_:
  line_list = list(file_)
  line_list.reverse()

  for line in line_list:
    if line.find(a) != -1:
      # do something
      print(line)
```

It is giving below output

```
bring it on
bring it on
bring it on
```

Expected output: find and print only those lines which have a string  `err`  after the last occurrence of a string `a`

```
[err] - there is no way
err - back
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following technique:

- The text file is opened, read and assigned to variable `text`.
- `text` is then split into sections using `'bring it on'` as a keyword
- The `last_section` is selected using `[-1]`
- Split the `last_section` into lines using `\n` as as keyword
- Find the lines that contain the word `err` in them and append them to the `errors` list
- print the errors within the `errors` list

```
with open('com.txt', 'r') as file_:
    text = file_.read()

last_section = text.split('bring it on')[-1]

errors = [line for line in last_section.split('\n') if 'err' in line]

for error in errors:
    print(error)
```

#### Output:

```
[err] - there is no way
err - back
```